# App uploaded to app store successfully but not shown in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

On Monday, I uploaded an app through the Xcode 7.3 successfully, but I couldn't see the build version in iTunes Connect all the time.

1. I have to make it clear that **I have been waiting for several days and I know it will show in about five minutes under normal circumstances**. I also have searched the stack overflow about this question. Nearly all the answers to such kind of questions told the user to wait for some time.
2. After the first try waiting for about two days but not seen the build version, I uploaded for the second time, but the Xcode reported an error about there was a duplicate version. It is very weird....

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same problem in these days. My solution is remake my certificate and profile and rebuild it.

Comment: Have you seen the build version in iTunes Connect after you took your solution??

Comment: @WeiweiYin Year, and now is waiting for preview.

Answer (score 2):

After I contacted Apple and logged in the email wanting to check whether Apple had replied, I found one email from Apple yesterday:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "XX". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Non-public API usage:
>
> The app references non-public symbols in XX: _UICreateCGImageFromIOSurface
>   If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed.
>
> If you think this message was sent in error and that you have only used Apple-published APIs in accordance with the guidelines, send the app's nine-digit Apple ID, along with detailed information about why you believe the above APIs were incorrectly flagged, to appreview@apple.com. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information page.
>
> Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to make you aware of them:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.
>
> Once the required corrections have been made, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

And I realized that there was some problem with my app. Finally, by searching the Internet I found it was the problem of the "Reveal Framework" debugging the UI I added earlier to my project. So when uploading the app I have to remove the **Reveal Framework**.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Contact/developer email which added to the app store. Sometimes 
iTunes Store will send an email include with exact reason. In my case, they mentioned about "Missing Purpose String" for "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" in info.plist